# Some CSS3 Animations not working in eBay Description

Tags: html, css, animation, ebay-design-templates

So eBay listings are hugely limited, but I don't see anything which suggests CSS3 wont work... I've been able to use @font-face, and some other CSS mouse over animations such as slightly zooming images out etc and they all work fine. I've also been able to add a spinning animation in another listing which happens when you hover on the image which again should suggest any CSS would work.

Previously any errors id seen with CSS has been with the way eBay parses the code and if there are any spaces it'll occasionally throw up a CSS parsing error, but once these are cleared everything runs fine, except this time where the animations still don't work.

The two phones in the following demo listing should tilt when you hover over them, but nothing is happening. Can anyone debug a reason why this might be?

Here is a test eBay listing
http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/NEW-Beats-by-Dr-Dre-Solo2-On-Ear-Headband-Headphones-Test-Listing-/301742453131

and here is a self hosted version which should work in all major browsers on OS X and Windows.
http://deecies.com/ip6test.html

Comment: On line 162 of the CSS (the :hover rule), there's a line break before the opening bracket {. I think that could probably be related to your issue?

Comment: Thanks David, you definitely caught something there! I deleted it and now it's *almost* working. In Safari when I mouse over the image disappears for some reason. Firefox and Chrome the image works fine though. Finally the fallback for Firefox and IE is to use lots of divs for the missing shape-outside, this works if you load the above link in either IE or Firefox but not when in eBay so again, some wrong syntax somewhere maybe, eBay appears to be the strictest browser going!

Comment: The two phones in your embedded section of the eBay page are tilting for me on both Firefox and Chrome (Mac OS X 10.11). Edit: didn't see above comment.

Comment: @DannyShepherd Hm that's odd indeed, the left-hand image is working for me now in Safari, just the right-hand image causing a problem. I'll try and debug a little more.

Comment: this rule: `.iphone6sfloatright:hover, .iphone6sfloatright:active` has a syntax error among the vendor prefixes, I think that's the problem with the right-hand image... Seeing as Chrome and FF use a prefix that doesn't have the error. Correcting the syntax fixed it for me in Safari dev tools

Comment: Thanks David you're a star, I found a few other erroneous spaces also in the extra code for IE and Firefox for the shape-outline hack. I restarted Safari and at first the animations worked fine and now every time I mouse over the image is disappearing again. It could be a Safari 9.01 bug perhaps. Though I can't create it in stand alone.

Comment: @DavidAlsbright was was the syntax error you found n the iphone6sfloatright:hover section? I cannot find anything and its not working in Safari (i'm also still getting the strange bug of the image disappearing in Safari when you mouse over which doesn't happen in any other browser...)

Comment: From what I can see when comparing the left phone hover values to the right, there's an extra `0.5s` at the end of the first vendor prefix for the right-hand phone (which Safari uses) I can't be 100% sure as i can only debug for about 15 seconds before Safari dev tools crashes spectacularly. That's only happening on your page, so i guess there's a deeper problem somewhere?

Comment: Hmmm yes, its very odd. So eBay has two views as mentioned below, first it puts all the content in a div, on refresh its an iframe. On first look the images animate fine when in the div, the second time when in the iframe they're disappearing on mouse over. This is the only bug i've got left :/

Comment: Another stab in the dark but could you disable caching for that page on the client side somehow?

Comment: Unfortunately not, we have no control over what eBay does - really strange that its the only browser with the problem when its embedded in the iframe.

Comment: Unfortunately I have zero experience of writing code for eBay pages. I guess a dirty workaround would be setting the phone image as a background for the element as a fall back, it won't rotate but at least it won't disappear. Aside from that I'm pretty much out of ideas I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

Doctype is the reason why some parts of CSS3 will not work on eBay Descriptions.

The Doctype on the iframe (which is where eBay throws your description) is not defined so it can default to html 4.

Here is something to keep in mind when building a template:

There is a known issue of First Load vs Cached Load on eBay. If you view your listing in non-cached incognito window you will see that eBay doesn't throw your description into an iFrame and the Doctype is defined as HTML5. But, if you reload the page you get back to your iframe HTML 4 doctype.

Comment: I was always under the impression that not including a doctype would revert most browsers into Quirks Mode, not HTML4. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi Isaac, thanks for the invaluable information there. I was aware that eBay did the caching thing with putting it in a div on first view and then an iframe on a second view and I found a bug in syntax that caused this error. I'm starting to wish I hadn't used an e-mail template to build from as a lot of the code is messy as hell so hard to find minor syntax that a browser forgives but not when embedded in eBay. Is it possible to define as HTML5 with a doctype in the description or will this always be ignored by the iframe?

Comment: Yes you can use an Iframe. Inside the iframe you can define the doctype to whatever you want, but in order to generate an iframe on eBay you will need to use something like document.write and use split up the word iframe with variables.